# Custom references page with additional line breaks

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking

Is it possible by any chance to style the references page to match this:

```
[1] The Author, The Author2
    "The title of some kind"
    3rd. edition ISBN: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

Comment: I've asked the Latex mods if they want this. On our sites we prefer some evidence of having "had a go" at solving problems rather than just outright asking for code/markup.

Comment: @Kev, i have read few articles but i cannot seem to find the "proper" way and perhaps a different which is less messy than normally. So i made the question a bit more open to receive alternatives. It seems unfair to become punished on this behalf. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the `openbib` option to the global options, for instance

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openbib]{report}
```

All the standard classes should honor it, but it may depend on the bibliography style you're using. More information is needed if this doesn't work.

Here's an example (the `filecontents*` environment is just to have a unique input file):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{knuth:texbook,
  author =       {Donald E. Knuth},
  title =        {The {\TeX}book},
  publisher =    {Addison Wesley},
  address =      {Reading, MA, USA},
  year =         1986,
  ISBN =         "0-201-13447-0",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[a4paper,openbib]{report}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to create your own bibtex style. It is normally not an easy task, but you can use a GUI tool for doing this easily as described here: http://bib-it.sourceforge.net/help/generateBibstyle.php