# Creating custom citation style

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I want to built a citation definition identical to this form: `[Author, [x], Year]`, where `x` is the citation number. Is it possible to do such thing? I am using  `openbib`.

Also is there a way that i can find which commands are valid with `openbib`, a Google search did not give me much.

I use the `cite` package.

EDIT:
I tried replcacing `cite` with `natbib` and used the `\citet` command, which gives following output: `(author?) [15]`, reference number is valid, and the reference has a author.

Comment: Openbib is a search engine and not related to LaTeX. However I recommend to use `biblatex`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel `openbib` is an old LaTeX2.09 style, I think

Comment: I was recommended `openbib` due to the requirements for my reference list style. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56628/custom-references-page-with-additional-line-breaks
If i change to biblatex, how can i maintain such style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

I replaced my `cite` package with: `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`
Added the `plainnat` style: `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`

And created following definition: `\def\citeAuthNumYr#1{[\citeauthor{#1}, \citep{#1}, \citeyear{#1}]}`